# Filter a string of commas and spaces that are random

Tags: powershell, replace, filter, split

I have a string that is user generated that I would like to split at the commas.

When the users create this string, they may put in extra commas or spaces between commas that are not useful or needed or cause issues later in my scripts; e.g.:

```
,   ,, ,,   ,H30332,B6235,,      ,,,,Y65454,,,M7373
```

This should get filtered down to:

```
H30332,B6235,Y65454,M7373
```

I have tried a few `-split`s and `-replace`s but I cant get it down to exactly what I need, I either end up with spaces in between or no commas and no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rawList = ',   ,, ,,   ,H30332,B6235,,      ,,,,Y65454,,,M7373'
($rawList -replace '[, ]+', ',').Trim(',')
```

- `-replace '[, ]+', ','` replaces any nonempty run of spaces and/or commas with a single comma
- `.Trim(',')` removes any leading or trailing comma.

The above yields `H30332,B6235,Y65454,M7373`, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Editor's note**: This *Java* answer was posted before the OP clarified that a *PowerShell* solution is sought.</sup>

This code gives you the output ,H30332,B6235,Y65454,M7373

```
    String str = ",   ,, ,,   ,H30332,B6235,,      ,,,,Y65454,,,M7373";

    String regex = "\\s";
    String replacement = "";
    String pattern = "(,*)(,)";

    str = str.replaceAll(regex, replacement);

    str = str.replaceAll(pattern, ",");
```

then you can remove the ',' at the start.

```
    str = str.substring(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

$string = ',   ,, ,,   ,H30332,B6235,,      ,,,,Y65454,,,M7373'

($string -replace ',+\s*',',' -replace '\s*,+',',').Trim(', ')

Comment: I see. Since it is a less straightforward near-duplicate of the now-accepted answer, can I suggest you delete it? If you do want to keep it, please format it properly.